# Cannot find name 'BigInt'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2020' or later

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compile my typescript file using `tsc index.ts` command, but it's showing me this error `Cannot find the name 'BigInt'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2020' or later.`

index.ts file code:

```
// string type
let a: string = "hello world";

// number type
let b: number = 5;

// boolean type
let c: boolean = true;

// null type
let d: null = null;

// bigint
let f: bigint = BigInt(100);

// symbol type
let g: symbol = Symbol("name");
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "files": ["./index.ts"]
}
```

Anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2020' or later.
```

This means you should add `lib` like so:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020"]
  },
  "files": ["./index.ts"]
}
```

Inside `lib` you would put all of the environment type definitions you need. For example, if I wanted to use ESNext and ESNext's async iterables, I would use:

```
"lib": ["esnext", "esnext.asynciterable"]
```

Strings given to `lib` are case-insensitive so `ESNEXT` would be the same as `esnext` or `ESNext`.

[Links to docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib)